# Seleccionar filas con criterio especifico de una columna, copiarlos en otra hoja y eliminarlos de la hoja origen GOOOGLE SHEETS (MACRO)

Tags: script, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, macros

Tengo:

**Hoja 1**: con tareas en cada fila y en una columna (**H**) una casilla de verificación con "OK" para seleccionar tareas finalizadas.
**Hoja 2**: para guardar las tareas hechas.

Lo que necesito es seleccionar de **Hoja 1** aquellas filas que tengan "OK", copiarlas o moverlas a la **Hoja 2**

Luego, quiero eliminar los registros copiados de la **hoja 1**

Todo esto en una macro de google sheets.

Ejemplo:
[image: solo copiar las filas con criterio de "OK"]

Agradecería la ayuda amigos

Comment: Al copiar en la Hoja 2, que pegue las filas en la ultima fila con celdas vacias para que se pueda ir acumulando en forma de lista.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor muestra lo que has intentado y agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: Puedes incluir una imagen de ejemplo?

Comment: function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Tareas');
  var r = s.getRange('H:H');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='OK')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};